# OkHttp and HTTP3 support

Tags: okhttp, http3

I would like to know information about HTTP v3 support in okhttp.
Someone knows when or if it will support the new HTTP version?
I see it would use injestors for this, but I haven't found anything updated about that.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the advantage of HTTP3 in Android?  Isn't HTTP2 adequate.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a bridging interceptor like https://github.com/google/cronet-transport-for-okhttp/blob/master/README.md

There are no plans for HTTP/3 support implemented in Kotlin inside of OkHttp. See https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/907